# Magento 2 - drop_down customizable option values no being populated

Tags: magento2, php, custom-options

I'm currently trying to import customizable options to lots of products. However, when trying to add values to a `drop_down` option type, the values aren't being displayed in the admin nor the frontend. However, no errors are being presented?

Please see script:

```
$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
$objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();
$state = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode('adminhtml');

$cli = getopt('', ['dryrun::']);

$productModel = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product');

$productCollection = $productModel->getCollection()->load()->getItems();

$updateCount = 0;

function getFontArray($sku) {
    $file = fopen('products_templates.csv', 'r');
    while (($line = fgetcsv($file)) !== FALSE) {
        if ($line[1] === $sku || strpos($sku, $line[1]) !== false) {
            return unserialize(str_replace('\\', '', $line[5]));
        }
    }
    fclose($file);

    return [];
}


/** @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product */
foreach ($productCollection as $product) {
    $customOptions = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Option')->getProductOptionCollection($product);

    $imageTemplate = $objectManager->get('Vendor\Module\Model\ImageTemplate');
    $templateCheck = null;

    $templateCheck = $imageTemplate->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('template_id', $product->getSku())->setOrder('row_count', 'desc')->load()->getFirstItem(); 

    if (!$templateCheck->getId()) {
        continue;
    }

    if (count($customOptions)) {
        foreach ($customOptions as $option) {
            if ($option->getData('title') == "Choose Font") {
                continue 2;
            }
        }
    }

    $fonts = getFontArray($product->getSku());
    $fontOptionData = [];
    if (count($fonts) && (int)$templateCheck->getRowCount()) {

        foreach ($fonts as $font) {
            $fontOptionData[] = [
                'title' => $font,
                'price' => 0,
                'price_type' => "fixed"
            ];
        } 

        $options = [];
        $sort_order = 0;

        if (count($fontOptionData)) {
            $options[] =
                [
                    "sort_order" => $sort_order,
                    "title" => "Choose Font",
                    "price_type" => "fixed",
                    "price" => 0.00,
                    "type" => "drop_down",
                    "is_require" => 0,
                    'product_sku' => $product->getSku(),
                    "values" => $fontOptionData
                ];
        }

        $sort_order++;

        for ($i = 0; $i < (int) $templateCheck->getRowCount(); $i++) {
            $options[] = [
                "sort_order" => $sort_order,
                "title" => "Line " . ($i+1),
                "price_type" => "fixed",
                "price" => "",
                "type" => "field",
                "is_require" => 0
            ];

            $sort_order++;
        }

        $product->setHasOptions(1);
        $product->setCanSaveCustomOptions(true);

        foreach ($options as $arrayOption) {
            $option = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Option')
                ->setProductId($product->getId())
                ->setStoreId($product->getStoreId())
                ->addData($arrayOption);

            if (!isset($cli['dryrun'])) {
                $option->save();
            }

            if (!isset($cli['dryrun'])) {
                $product->addOption($option); 
            }
        }

        if (!isset($cli['dryrun'])) {
            $product->getResource()->save($product);
        }
    }

    echo 'DONE' . PHP_EOL; 

    $updateCount++;
}

echo $updateCount . PHP_EOL;
```

Can anyone see why this is not creating the `drop_down` correctly? This is an example of the `$options` array:

```
array(3) { [0]=> array(8) { ["sort_order"]=> int(0) ["title"]=> string(11) "Choose Font" ["price_type"]=> string(5) "fixed" ["price"]=> float(0) ["type"]=> string(9) "drop_down" ["is_require"]=> int(0) ["product_sku"]=> string(19) "123456" ["values"]=> array(4) { [0]=> array(3) { ["title"]=> string(7) "dancing" ["price"]=> int(0) ["price_type"]=> string(5) "fixed" } [1]=> array(3) { ["title"]=> string(8) "mtcorsva" ["price"]=> int(0) ["price_type"]=> string(5) "fixed" } [2]=> array(3) { ["title"]=> string(7) "english" ["price"]=> int(0) ["price_type"]=> string(5) "fixed" } [3]=> array(3) { ["title"]=> string(5) "nyala" ["price"]=> int(0) ["price_type"]=> string(5) "fixed" } } } [1]=> array(6) { ["sort_order"]=> int(1) ["title"]=> string(6) "Line 1" ["price_type"]=> string(5) "fixed" ["price"]=> string(0) "" ["type"]=> string(5) "field" ["is_require"]=> int(0) } [2]=> array(6) { ["sort_order"]=> int(2) ["title"]=> string(6) "Line 2" ["price_type"]=> string(5) "fixed" ["price"]=> string(0) "" ["type"]=> string(5) "field" ["is_require"]=> int(0) } }
```